# PowerShell to start only running Host Instances

Tags: powershell, biztalk, biztalk-2010

We have an windows clustered environment with clustered FTP and MQ host instances and non clustered host instances.

I want to be able to restart the running host instances only.  I have a script to start all host instances but we do not want to start the stopped ones on the passive cluster node.  I have a script to start all host instances.

Anyone have any ideas how to only start running ones other than a script that reads from a list of specific host instances?

Comment: Could you post what you have already?

Comment: I have this one I believe I got here.  It works on my BT2013 non clustered environment fine. See below comment

Comment: #restart host instances
[ARRAY]$hostInstances = get-wmiobject MSBTS_HostInstance -namespace "root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer" -Filter "(HostType = 1)"

write-host ("Total Number of Host Instance : "+$hostInstances.Count) -Fore Yellow
Write-Host “Re-starting Host instance” -Fore Yellow

foreach ($hostInstance in $hostInstances)
{
$hostInstance.Stop()
$hostInstance.Start()
}

Write-Host “Host instances are restarted successfully” -Fore Green

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add any new information rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing with the @jcarreiro solution, you have to get the Host Instances, filtering by HostType = 1 and ServiceState = 4.

**The values of Host Type are**: **1 - In-process**, 2 - Isolated

**The values of ServiceState are**: 1 - Stopped, 2 - Start pending, 3 - Stop pending, **4 - Running**, 5 - Continue pending, 6 - Pause pending, 7 - Paused, 8 - Unknown

```
[ARRAY]$hostInstances = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_HostInstance -namespace "root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer" -Filter "(HostType = 1 and ServiceState = 4)" 
Write-Host ("Total Number of Host Instances running : "+$hostInstances.Count) -Fore Yellow 
Write-Host “Re-starting Host instance” -Fore Yellow 

foreach ($hostInstance in $hostInstances) 
{ 
    $hostInstance.Stop()
    $hostInstance.Start()
}

Write-Host “Host instances are restarted successfully” -Fore Green
```